# Gather list items by position

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
list = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}};
```

Independently of the size of each sublist (`Length[sublist1]===Length[sublist2]>=1`), I need to gather each element of both sublist in the following manner:

```
{{a, d}, {b, e}, {c, f}}
```

Does anyone know what to do in this case?

I thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: ``Transpose[list]``

Comment: ``ArrayReshape[Transpose@{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}, {3, 2}]`` it works. Thanks a lot, Domen.

Comment: I list all the pairing since I mistook your meaning :-)  `Thread /@ Tuples[Permutations /@ list]`

Comment: `Thread[list]` also works, as does `Flatten[list, {{2}, {1}}]`, but I usually use `Transpose`. (Always use `Transpose` on packed arrays.)

Comment: I remember that, @cvgmt :-)

Comment: @Michael E2 Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestion! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lst = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}};
Transpose@lst

(*  {{a, d}, {b, e}, {c, f}}  *)
```

Have fun!